# onChange Function not triggering when sheet is changed by another script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a app script Web App with a calendar, the calendar gets it's data from a master spreadsheet. A user can click on the item (on the calendar) to change the data: such as date, time, what they did, what happened, etc. These changes gets submitted to a "dump" spreadsheet, and then those changes are supposed to get copied over to the master spreadsheet.

The issue is, when the web app form is submitted, the dump sheet is being changed by a script. This causes the onChange trigger on the dumpSheet to NOT run, and in turn the submitted data is not being copied over to the master sheet.

How can I work around this issue? I could do a Time driven trigger to submit the changes, but then the issue is that the user would have to wait to see his changes in the web app calendar. And I would be running the function unnecessarily, wasting my app script quota.

Comment: Cut the middleman out

Comment: By design, script modifications do not activate triggering events. If a script should activate another script, call it directly.

Comment: the middleman sheet is neccesary so that users are not able to view/edit/change the master sheet.  But gotcha, thank you.